# copy and paste as values to another sheet, excel macro

Tags: excel-formula

I'm new with Macro and I want to create a simple copy and paste excel formula from one sheet to another. But the thing is the main data has a formula inside the cell and it wont let me copy and paste as values it to another cell.

```
Sub selectpasting()
Dim Lastrow As Long, erow As Long


Lastrow = Sheets("attendance").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To Lastrow


   If Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 3) = "absent" Then

    Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 1).copy
    erow = Sheets("forpasting").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    Sheets("attendance").Paste Destination:=Sheets("forpasting").Cells(erow, 1)


    Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 3).copy
    Sheets("attendance").Paste Destination:=Sheets("forpasting").Cells(erow, 2)

End If

Next i


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("forpasting").Columns.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy only formulas from one excel sheet which can dynamically grow to another sheet using macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459563/how-to-copy-only-formulas-from-one-excel-sheet-which-can-dynamically-grow-to-ano)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this row:

```
Sheets("attendance").Paste Destination:=Sheets("forpasting").Cells(erow, 1)
```

To:

```
Sheets("forpasting").Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

**The complete code would be:**

```
Sub selectpasting()
Dim Lastrow As Long, erow As Long
Dim i As Long

Lastrow = Sheets("attendance").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To Lastrow


   If Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 3) = "absent" Then

    Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 1).Copy
    erow = Sheets("forpasting").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    Sheets("forpasting").Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues


    Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 3).Copy
    Sheets("forpasting").Cells(erow, 2).PasteSpecial xlValues
End If

Next i


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("forpasting").Columns.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

---

The code above is quite slow (try both the codes and you would notice that the below is way faster).. The reason is that in the above excel needs to determine/evaluate if the the cell properties needs to be pasted or not due to "`.copy`". It's one approach when you need to copy/paste cell formats etc.

In your case you only interested in the value the cells shows. So you could just pick the value and copy it.

I would therefore recommend you to change it to:

```
Sub selectpasting_2()
Dim Lastrow As Long, erow As Long
Dim i As Long

Lastrow = Sheets("attendance").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To Lastrow


   If Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 3) = "absent" Then


    erow = Sheets("forpasting").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    Sheets("forpasting").Cells(erow, 1) = Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 1)

    Sheets("forpasting").Cells(erow, 2) = Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 3)
End If

Next i


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("forpasting").Columns.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Great, it did work. You saved my life. This is awesome. Hoping that you can help me on my future journey inside Macro. God Bless you!

Comment: Hi, :). I'm not sure if I understand what you want to achieve... If you also want to use "`If Sheets("attendance").Cells(i, 3) = "time" Then`" you could add a `ElseIf` statement. Reference how to use you can find [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php). Otherwise I would suggest you to create a new question with some example/pictures of what you want to achieve and people will for sure help you, including me =)!!

Comment: Looking forwarding for the next questions I might have that I know you can answer. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hi Sir, I was able to answer my own question :)  eheh. Thanks anyways

Comment: Great!! I'm impressed :). You are always welcome to ask :). Good luck with your project!.